# I want to get a string from MySQL db and modify it and save it back to the DB

Tags: python, mysql, django

The problem is the string in the db has '\' in it and I want to read this string ,modify it and save it back to the DB. SQL automatically removes any escape characters . So \ is removed from the string and saved in the DB.

eg:

```
config = '{"Settings":"{\"On\"}"}'
sql= "INSERT INTO file (configuration, id) VALUES('%s', '%s')" % (config, 
cursor.execute(sql)
```

and in the DB `{"Settings":"{"On"}"}` is saved.

Comment: Why do you use a raw query instead of the Django ORM? This is terribly unsafe w.r.t. SQL injection.

Comment: And even if you had to use a raw query, you should **never** use string interpolation like that.

Comment: Furthermore it is *not* saved that wway in the database, it contains no backslash itself. The backslash is the *representation* of the string.

Comment: Thank You for replying. but that is how it is saved in the db. maybe someone who stored it in the db before had used double backslashes. 

So is there any way to store in to the db with the backslashes.. 
ps. i dont want to use replace to duplicate the backslashes in the config. 


eg like we use 'r' in python to treat it as rawstring, is there any method to be followed in sql?

Comment: is the column actually a JSON type? What MySQL version?

Comment: the column type is 'longtext' but a json like string is saved in it